# as resilient as they come

Tags: meaning

Obama said to Carter, "Jimmy, you're as resilient as they come, and along with the rest of America, we are rooting for you."

What does "they" refer to in "as resilient as they come?"

Comment: "As xxx as they come" is an idiom meaning that the individual being described has the utmost degree of xxx.

Answer (score 2):

**They**, in this instance, stands for

> **People in general**: "the rest, as they say, is history"
>
> *[-Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/they)*

But in "Jimmy, you're as resilient as they come", the meaning of the whole phrase is rather particular. "As ___ as they come" is an idiom that means "as much as possible."

> **As [something] as they come:** as much of a particular characteristic as is possible.  *Eric is as competitive as they come and always trying to win.* - *[Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+as+they+come)*

So what your quote is saying is something like: "Jimmy, as people come, no-one is more resilient".

(Incidentally, if you search for a word in a dictionary and can't understand the definition, it can be useful to search online for the phrase it's in. You're more likely to catch idiomatic usage that way.)

Answer (score 0):

The phrase "as resilient as they come" means *as resilient as the most resilient people I know.*